# Style guideline/convention for defining binary operator in a class (C++)

Tags: c++

This is a bit of a general question, but I have some classes that I'd like to define some binary "operations" on, and there are several different ways of doing so. For example, suppose I have a `Vector` class that I'd like to implement an addition operation on. On one hand, I could just overload the `'+'` operator, but I have read from a few sources that this isn't a very good practice (which begs one to ask why this is a language feature at all). I can see in many cases why methods are preferable to operator overloading, but vector addition is widely agreed upon and so using `'+'` should be very natural.

On the other hand, I could define an `add()` method in the class. I could just define it as a normal method and use `x.add(y)` to perform `x + y`, but it doesn't showcase itself as a binary operator so I'm not sure if this should be preferred. I could also define it as a static method, for instance `Vector.add(x, y)`. Finally, I could also define `add()` as a friend function of the class, which is very (mathematically) natural but in my opinion is a bit contrary to the philosophy of `OOP`. I'm hoping to get a bit of insight into which methods are preferable (and why).

Comment: `Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &lhs, const Vector &rhs) { Vector v = lhs; v += rhs; return v; }` is defined in terms of `operator +=`.  I believe that when you're defining operators, that's generally a good style to adopt (define operator `@` in terms of `@=`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is to define reflexive operators (`+=`, `*=`, etc.) as members that modify the object they are applied to, and to define non-reflexive operators (`+`, `*`, etc.) as non-members that create a copy of one of their arguments, use the corresponding reflexive operator to do the operation, and return the new object as their result.

While Java programmers believe that `add` functions are a good thing, they do so because Java doesn't have operator overloading. Named operations lead to **really** long and unreadable expressions for things that should be simple.

Comment: Well I'm certainly glad to hear that this is considered an acceptable practice. It's the most natural and convenient way, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage to defining your binary operator as a friend function (potentially as a set of overloads) is to permit the left-hand value to be other than an instance of your class.  This is commonly done for stream inserters/extractors.  Note that the friend status is only necessary if your operator requires access to the internals of one of its operands.  It's best if the operator can work through the public interfaces of each operand, avoiding the need for friend and the resulting tighter coupling.

Comment: Interesting. Could that not also be achieved through just a normal method declaration? For example, the dot product of two vectors should take two vectors as input and output just a number, but this is certainly possible by just writing a class method.

Comment: The non-member approach is necessary to accommodate arbitrary ordering of operands, such as when the left-value is a primitive.  Imagine a scalar operator* for your vector class, where you'd want to support scalar * vector as well as vector * scalar.  Another good example is string's operator+:

 std::string s1("world");
 std::string s2 = "hello, " + s1;

Comment: @Andrew Martin: I would preserve `v_ * w_` for algebra over a field's bi-linear op and use whatever::scalar_product for <v_,w_>.

Comment: I agree, I don't think a scalar product should really be considered an operation. From a mathematics perspective it isn't, so I'll just write a method for that. Thanks!